# How can I control the density or probability of an object based on material using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm new to blender. I'm wondering using the attached node layout, where I use multiple 'set materials' how I would be able to control the probability of one of these materials appearing. Specifically the material 'sticker.oo1'.

[image]

[image: Geometry Nodes]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this node setup...

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Note1: i changed your sticker color of 001 to pink so that i could see something - in your blend file it was just black

Note2: important that this works: you have to make sure, that your material 001 goes first into the instance node like this:

[image]

The node setup is pretty basic: a probabilty will be defined by boolean random value. This controls a switch whether it uses instance 0 (integer node 0) or a random value from 1 to 7 (which are the other instances)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much for your help I'll remember this!

Answer (score 3):

I figured, it might be convenient to have an interface like so:

[image]

Here  *Blue* material has the same chance to appear as ⬛ *Black*.  *Green* has twice the base chance, meaning it statistically appears as often as *Black* and *Blue* combined.  *Red* will fill just a quarter of the area *Green* fills, and ⬜ *White* is very rare, 5 times rarer than *Red*. The probability could be presented as a chart:

⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬛⬜

Of course if those *cumulative weights* are confusing, feel free to just set the values to percentages, in this case it would be: $22\%$⬛$22\%$$44\%$$10\%$⬜$2\%$ (some arbitrary rounding was done)

The real result of the above:

[image]

Obviously other than provided *Seed*, it would be nice to allow for some grouping, where you would plug in a *Mesh Island: Island Index* for example. I'll leave it for anyone interested to edit in, as basically you would just plug it into the *ID* of the *Random* node (select the node and press <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to reveal hidden sockets).

**Add Material** group:

[image]

**Randomize Materials** group:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reading the question again, I might have misunderstood the question (or I did understand it but the title is bad), might need to find a better place for this answer :P

Comment: Thanks for your input. Looks interesting I'll play around with your settings when I get home.