# Retaining materials though simulation nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, simulation-nodes

I am using the new simulation nodes to have an object rotate randomly, when the object leaves the simulation node block: all it's materials are gone. I can't seem to find a way to reapply them. There are 2 differrent materials and I have tried using vertex groups to select only the correct faces, but that hasn't worked.

I'm verry new to geo/sim nodes so please bear with me.

the selection input is the material index, I have also tried it as a vertex group.
[image: A blender geo nodes tree]

This is what it should look like:
[image]

This is setting the jewel material
[image]

but trying to add the metal before that stops it from working
[image]

Comment: pls show at least your node tree so we see what you did ...or provide your blend file so we can check it out. thx

Answer (score 3):

[Issue #108410: Geometry Nodes: Support materials in simulation state.](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/108410)

> Currently, the simulation state in geometry nodes cannot contain materials.

What you want to do, is to capture an integer attribute, and then - after the simulation - assign materials based on this attribute.

Here's an example:

[How can I control the density or probability of an object based on material using geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296854/60486)

Specifically the very end of my answer:

[image]

If I remember well, I Set Material to nothing, in order to have just one material index $0$ on "Geometry", and join the "Materials Collection" afterwards, to have 1-based indexing, because it was fitting my setup. Otherwise you could swap the join order, and resign from "Set Material" node.

Comment: Would it be possible to get a more detailed explanation, please? I have no idea how capturing an integer attribute translates into assigning materials where they belong.

Comment: @Macciavelo see edit.