# Geometry Nodes: How To Place Bias on Random Instance?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a collection of 4 objects that I'm instancing to points on a grid.  Right now the randomness is spread evenly (more or less) but I want one of the objects in the collection to be the most prevalent, and the other three to be more sparse.

What would be a good way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a color ramp to easily and visually give weight to all possibilities:

[image]

The colors are there only to clearly distinct which swatch is which, but the actual data controlling the instance index is the *Alpha* of the swatches: the 1st has alpha $ = 0$,
2nd swatch alpha $ = 1$, 3rd swatch alpha $=2$ and 4th swatch alpha $ = 3$.

Result:

[image]

If you don't know in advance how many instances you have and want to somehow dynamically get a weighted random integer, see my solution here:

[How can I control the density or probability of an object based on material using geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296854/60486)

Comment: Markus this is brilliant, thank you, I would have never thought to go this route.  Can't wait to try it out.

Comment: Hey Markus, after playing with this solution it isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  But I do appreciate its usefulness, just not in this 'instance' (pun intended, sorry, had to).  Is there a way to create a similar solution, but where I can use a numerical value (for instance between 1 and 10) to set the likelihood of an object being instanced in the grid?  What I need specifically is to be able to control the bias with a Group Input.

Comment: @GlenCandle Have you seen the linked solution with material distribution?

Comment: I'm examining it now and trying to understand how to translate that to my current setup. Bonus question: Using that solution, or another solution, would this also be a way to control bias for a random rotation?  E.g. only randomly rotate a random selection of 10% of the tiles?  (Sorry, my background is in filmmaking, math isn't my strong suit.)

Comment: @GlenCandle for that it seems you can just use "Random" node in "boolean" mode. 10% probability, connect it as selection, and connect another random ("vector") as rotation...

Comment: Oh this works beautifully.  All I had to do was add an additional Rotate Instances node after the Instance on Points node and viola!  Thanks Markus.