# geometry nodes, Weighted random value

Tags: geometry-nodes

how to define weighted random value?

for example in this node group, I want the **probability** of **smaller numbers** **to be more** than **bigger numbers**.

I tried using **map range** but I couldn't get any results.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could distribute points on a curve, with the accumulate weight becoming a factor to sample, as I do here: [How can I control the density or probability of an object based on material using geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/296854/60486)

Comment: use a random value set to float between 0 and 1, then use a math power node afterwards then remap to desired range.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady thank u

Comment: @shmuel Thank u, it works fine, for some reason, when I use "inverse square root" it gives me a better result, but I don't know much about math.

Comment: hmm,  wouldn't recommend. you could get very hight numbers with that. it is the same as $1 \over \sqrt{x}$ or $ 1 \over x^{0.5}$ and taking the reciprocal of a low number could give very big numbers. anyway, if it works it works.